# send email by postfix - 454 4.7.1 Relay access denied

Tags: centos, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I configure mail server by Postfix and Dovecot.

I can receive and send mail in my server and check by telnet on port 25, but I can't send email from my local system by Thunderbird and get this response:

> An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:
>   454 4.7.1 : Relay access denied.
>   Please check the message recipient "soroush@hotmail.com" and try again

**In the event that I can send email from my server.**

**Notice: my server hasn't SSL!**

postfix/main.conf:

```
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = www.example.com
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox = Maildir/
debug_peer_level = 2
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
```

can Anybody help me?

Comment: You really should read this book here: https://www.mobt3ath.com/uplode/book/book-27297.pdf - because if you are unable to understand such a basic error message it means that you've got no experience whatsoever in running a MTA nor what it does, or how to protect it to become an open SPAM relay if hooked up unto the internet.

Comment: An e-mail server will not send (relay) untrusted e-mail to a remote e-mail server. Usually an e-mail is trusted if it comes from a specific IP address range (cf. [What client to relay mail from](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#relay_from)) or from an authenticated user (cf. [SASL authentication](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html)).